# Запуск скрипта в python по нажатию горячей клавиши

Tags: python, python-3.x, hotkeys

Можно ли как-нибудь реализовать что бы я нажимал к примеру Ctrl + N и выполнялся кусок кода и при этом на экран ничего не выводилось.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Есть модуль [keyboard](https://github.com/boppreh/keyboard) (установка через `pip install keyboard`):

```
import keyboard


def foo():
    print('World')


keyboard.add_hotkey('Ctrl + 1', lambda: print('Hello'))
keyboard.add_hotkey('Ctrl + 2', foo)

keyboard.wait('Ctrl + Q')
```

При клике на `Ctrl + Q` код будет дальше выполняться и если ничего после нет, скрипт завершится